# Добавление, построение данных на страницы post в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Как лучше/правильнее реализовать динамическое добавление полей с формы в запись.

С возможностью в дальнейшем редактировать информацию с админ панели.

Правильно ли так делать:

```
foreach( $_POST['amount'] as $key => $n ) { 
  $key++;
  update_post_meta($post_id, 'key_'.$key, sanitize_text_field( $n )); 
}
```